# Generate Alphanumeric String on PHP

Tags: php

I was trying to make a Alphanumeric string and use it for a unique field in my database , it is not a replacement of the Primary key mind it . The following code is generating a 22 length text but my concern is will it continue to produce unique strings as i might need it for unique identification of the data.

```
<?php

$len =22;

$rand = substr(str_shuffle(md5(time())),0,$len);

echo $rand;

?>
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard That's incorrect, if its ran at the same time (unlikely but very possible)

Comment: You're right @JoeyCiechanowicz, I was just going with the odds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **openssl_random_pseudo_bytes** - it will Generate a pseudo-random string of bytes

and the **bin2hex()** function converts a string of ASCII characters to hexadecimal values

It will provide you secure token

```
bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length))
```

Comment: yes...it is the most secute token generator as per my research

Comment: Works as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
 $random = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

   $string = '';
 for ($i = 0; $i < $string_length; $i++) {
      $string .= $random [rand(0, strlen($random ) - 1)];
 }
```

$string_length is the length of your desired string.It will continue giving you unique strings.

Answer (score 0):

I will always include the `time()` in the resulting string to make sure it's unique, if first 10 characters are all numerical will be acceptable to you:

```
$rand = substr(time().str_shuffle(md5(time())),0,$len);
```

The function `str_shuffle(md5(time()))` is very unlikely to produce same results within a second.

This is the easiest way aside from manually checking the records of the existence of the random string for uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php provided method uniqid().